CMake trying to link a DLL Boost library when specifically stipulating a static build
Objective: using CMake with Visual Studio 2022 to build SimpleAmqpClient as a static library.
I have built RabbitMQ-C as a static library and I am trying to get a builld of the SimpleAmqpClient library (again as a static build). SimpleAmqpClient requires the Boost Chrono library and I have specifically told  CMake what static library to use. However, when I come to cmake --build . --config Release CMake is trying to find boost_chrono-vc143-mt-x64_1_80.lib (the DLL headers) rather than the static library libboost_chrono-vc142-mt-x64-1_80.lib
My command line invocation for the initial CMake is:
cmake -G "Visual Studio 17 2022" -A x64 ^
-DBoost_INCLUDE_DIR="C:/SIM_PACKAGES/boost_1_80_0" ^
-DBOOST_ROOT="C:/SIM_PACKAGES/boost_1_80_0" ^
-DBOOST_LIBRARYDIR="C:/SIM_PACKAGES/boost_1_80_0/stage/lib" ^
-DRabbitmqc_INCLUDE_DIR="C:/AmqpPackages/rabbitmq-c-master/rabbitmq-c-master/include" ^
-DRabbitmqc_LIBRARY="C:/AmqpPackages/rabbitmq-c-master/rabbitmq-c-master/build/librabbitmq/Release/librabbitmq.4.lib" ^
-DBoost_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS="1.80 1.80.0" ^
-DBoost_USE_STATIC_LIBS=ON ^
-DBoost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME=ON ^
-DBoost_USE_MULTITHREADED=ON ^
-DBoost_CHRONO_LIBRARY="C:/SIM_PACKAGES/boost_1_80_0/stage/lib/libboost_chrono-vc143-mt-x64-1_80.lib" ^
-DENABLE_SSL_SUPPORT=OFF ^

Then I attempt to build using cmake --build . --config Release and get:
MSBuild version 17.9.5+33de0b227 for .NET Framework

  1>Checking Build System
  Building Custom Rule C:/AmqpPackages/SimpleAmqpClient-master/SimpleAmqpClient-master/CMakeLists.txt
  AmqpException.cpp
  warning: amqp.h is deprecated, use rabbitmq-c/amqp.h instead.
  warning: amqp_framing.h is deprecated, use rabbitmq-c/framing.h instead.
  Channel.cpp
  warning: amqp.h is deprecated, use rabbitmq-c/amqp.h instead.
  warning: amqp_framing.h is deprecated, use rabbitmq-c/framing.h instead.
  warning: amqp_tcp_socket.h is deprecated, use rabbitmq-c/tcp_socket.h instead.
C:\AmqpPackages\SimpleAmqpClient-master\SimpleAmqpClient-master\src\SimpleAmqpClient\BadUriException.h(41,61): warning
C4275: non dll-interface class 'std::runtime_error' used as base for dll-interface class 'AmqpClient::BadUriException'
[C:\AmqpPackages\SimpleAmqpClient-master\SimpleAmqpClient-master\build\SimpleAmqpClient.vcxproj]
  (compiling source file '../src/Channel.cpp')
  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\include\stdexcept(100,19):
  see declaration of 'std::runtime_error'
  C:\AmqpPackages\SimpleAmqpClient-master\SimpleAmqpClient-master\src\SimpleAmqpClient\BadUriException.h(41,31):
  see declaration of 'AmqpClient::BadUriException'

C:\AmqpPackages\SimpleAmqpClient-master\SimpleAmqpClient-master\src\SimpleAmqpClient\ConsumerCancelledException.h(49,19
): warning C4275: non dll-interface class 'std::runtime_error' used as base for dll-interface class 'AmqpClient::Consum
erCancelledException' [C:\AmqpPackages\SimpleAmqpClient-master\SimpleAmqpClient-master\build\SimpleAmqpClient.vcxproj]
  (compiling source file '../src/Channel.cpp')
  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\include\stdexcept(100,19):
  see declaration of 'std::runtime_error'
  C:\AmqpPackages\SimpleAmqpClient-master\SimpleAmqpClient-master\src\SimpleAmqpClient\ConsumerCancelledException.h(48,
  31):
  see declaration of 'AmqpClient::ConsumerCancelledException'

C:\AmqpPackages\SimpleAmqpClient-master\SimpleAmqpClient-master\src\SimpleAmqpClient\ConsumerCancelledException.h(64,15
): warning C4251: 'AmqpClient::ConsumerCancelledException::m_consumer_tag': class 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_tra
its<char>,std::allocator<char>>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'AmqpClient::ConsumerCancel
ledException' [C:\AmqpPackages\SimpleAmqpClient-master\SimpleAmqpClient-master\build\SimpleAmqpClient.vcxproj]
  (compiling source file '../src/Channel.cpp')
  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\include\xstring(2337,7):
  see declaration of 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>'

C:\AmqpPackages\SimpleAmqpClient-master\SimpleAmqpClient-master\src\Channel.cpp(146,31): warning C4996: 'strdup': The P
OSIX name for this item is deprecated. Instead, use the ISO C and C++ conformant name: _strdup. See online help for det
ails. [C:\AmqpPackages\SimpleAmqpClient-master\SimpleAmqpClient-master\build\SimpleAmqpClient.vcxproj]
C:\AmqpPackages\SimpleAmqpClient-master\SimpleAmqpClient-master\src\Channel.cpp(493,37): warning C4101: 'e': unreferenc
ed local variable [C:\AmqpPackages\SimpleAmqpClient-master\SimpleAmqpClient-master\build\SimpleAmqpClient.vcxproj]
C:\AmqpPackages\SimpleAmqpClient-master\SimpleAmqpClient-master\src\Channel.cpp(617,37): warning C4101: 'e': unreferenc
ed local variable [C:\AmqpPackages\SimpleAmqpClient-master\SimpleAmqpClient-master\build\SimpleAmqpClient.vcxproj]
  ChannelImpl.cpp
  warning: amqp.h is deprecated, use rabbitmq-c/amqp.h instead.
  warning: amqp_framing.h is deprecated, use rabbitmq-c/framing.h instead.
C:\AmqpPackages\SimpleAmqpClient-master\SimpleAmqpClient-master\src\SimpleAmqpClient\ConsumerCancelledException.h(49,19
): warning C4275: non dll-interface class 'std::runtime_error' used as base for dll-interface class 'AmqpClient::Consum
erCancelledException' [C:\AmqpPackages\SimpleAmqpClient-master\SimpleAmqpClient-master\build\SimpleAmqpClient.vcxproj]
  (compiling source file '../src/ChannelImpl.cpp')
  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\include\stdexcept(100,19):
  see declaration of 'std::runtime_error'
  C:\AmqpPackages\SimpleAmqpClient-master\SimpleAmqpClient-master\src\SimpleAmqpClient\ConsumerCancelledException.h(48,
  31):
  see declaration of 'AmqpClient::ConsumerCancelledException'

C:\AmqpPackages\SimpleAmqpClient-master\SimpleAmqpClient-master\src\SimpleAmqpClient\ConsumerCancelledException.h(64,15
): warning C4251: 'AmqpClient::ConsumerCancelledException::m_consumer_tag': class 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_tra
its<char>,std::allocator<char>>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'AmqpClient::ConsumerCancel
ledException' [C:\AmqpPackages\SimpleAmqpClient-master\SimpleAmqpClient-master\build\SimpleAmqpClient.vcxproj]
  (compiling source file '../src/ChannelImpl.cpp')
  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\include\xstring(2337,7):
  see declaration of 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>'

C:\AmqpPackages\SimpleAmqpClient-master\SimpleAmqpClient-master\src\SimpleAmqpClient\ConnectionClosedException.h(44,19)
: warning C4275: non dll-interface class 'std::runtime_error' used as base for dll-interface class 'AmqpClient::Connect
ionClosedException' [C:\AmqpPackages\SimpleAmqpClient-master\SimpleAmqpClient-master\build\SimpleAmqpClient.vcxproj]
  (compiling source file '../src/ChannelImpl.cpp')
  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\include\stdexcept(100,19):
  see declaration of 'std::runtime_error'
  C:\AmqpPackages\SimpleAmqpClient-master\SimpleAmqpClient-master\src\SimpleAmqpClient\ConnectionClosedException.h(43,3
  1):
  see declaration of 'AmqpClient::ConnectionClosedException'

C:\AmqpPackages\SimpleAmqpClient-master\SimpleAmqpClient-master\src\ChannelImpl.cpp(176,25): warning C4244: 'return': c
onversion from '__int64' to 'amqp_channel_t', possible loss of data [C:\AmqpPackages\SimpleAmqpClient-master\SimpleAmqp
Client-master\build\SimpleAmqpClient.vcxproj]
C:\AmqpPackages\SimpleAmqpClient-master\SimpleAmqpClient-master\src\ChannelImpl.cpp(215,13): warning C4244: 'return': c
onversion from '__int64' to 'amqp_channel_t', possible loss of data [C:\AmqpPackages\SimpleAmqpClient-master\SimpleAmqp
Client-master\build\SimpleAmqpClient.vcxproj]
  BasicMessage.cpp
  warning: amqp.h is deprecated, use rabbitmq-c/amqp.h instead.
  warning: amqp_framing.h is deprecated, use rabbitmq-c/framing.h instead.
  AmqpLibraryException.cpp
  warning: amqp.h is deprecated, use rabbitmq-c/amqp.h instead.
  AmqpResponseLibraryException.cpp
  warning: amqp.h is deprecated, use rabbitmq-c/amqp.h instead.
  Envelope.cpp
  MessageReturnedException.cpp
  Table.cpp
  warning: amqp.h is deprecated, use rabbitmq-c/amqp.h instead.
  TableImpl.cpp
  warning: amqp.h is deprecated, use rabbitmq-c/amqp.h instead.
C:\AmqpPackages\SimpleAmqpClient-master\SimpleAmqpClient-master\src\TableImpl.cpp(159,41): warning C4267: '=': conversi
on from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data [C:\AmqpPackages\SimpleAmqpClient-master\SimpleAmqpClient-master\build
\SimpleAmqpClient.vcxproj]
C:\AmqpPackages\SimpleAmqpClient-master\SimpleAmqpClient-master\src\TableImpl.cpp(204,37): warning C4267: '=': conversi
on from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data [C:\AmqpPackages\SimpleAmqpClient-master\SimpleAmqpClient-master\build
\SimpleAmqpClient.vcxproj]
  Generating Code...
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'boost_chrono-vc143-mt-x64-1_80.lib' [C:\AmqpPackages\SimpleAmqpClient-mas
ter\SimpleAmqpClient-master\build\SimpleAmqpClient.vcxproj]


Apologies because this is no help at all, but sometimes I think CMake is more complicated than the problem it is trying to solve.

Don't you explicitly request for boost_chrono-vc143-mt-x64-1_80 through your CMake when writing
-DBoost_CHRONO_LIBRARY="C:/SIM_PACKAGES/boost_1_80_0/stage/lib/libboost_chrono-vc143-mt-x64-1_80.lib" ^ ??

I have tried setting DBoost_CHRONO_LIBRARY, but this didn't work.

It seems that building a working static library for SimpleAmqpClient is a mystery too deep and one that I don't have time to investigate. Thanks for the comments guys, but I'm going to stick with the DLL as this seems to be the only thing it's happy with.

The project SimpleAmqpClient by default expects dynamic Boost and links with the special target Boost::dynamic_linking in its CMakeLists.txt.
You may set the (project-specific) option Boost_Dynamic_Linking_ENABLED to OFF for make the project to expect the static Boost:
cmake -DBoost_Dynamic_Linking_ENABLED=OFF <...other options>

This will automatically set Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS to ON, so you don't need to repeat that setting.
But if you want to build the project itself with static libraries, then set BUILD_SHARED_LIBS option to OFF:
cmake -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS =OFF <...other options>

This will automatically set Boost_Dynamic_Linking_ENABLED to OFF.

Thank you very much for taking the time to answer. I have a build of the library now. But now I have an issue trying to link the library to my application. I have a whole load of LNK2001 errors like _imp_amqp_error_string2 telling me I have 24 unresolved externals. Any ideas here please? I've added the path and libraries for both rabbitmq-c and simpleAmqpClient to the linker options.

Prefix "imp" means that your application expects functions to be contained in the shared (dll) library. You need to define macro SimpleAmqpClient_STATIC for use static variant of the library.

Thanks once again. I've tried the following, putting:
#define SimpleAmqpClient_STATIC
#define SimpleAmqpClient_STATIC 1
#define SimpleAmqpClient_STATIC true in my code, but these don't solve the issue. I'm probably doing something wrong?

Without looking into your code it is difficult to say what do you do wrongly. You may ask new question and incorporate all needed information into it.
